# Ajax post form doesn't load

Tags: php, jquery, session

This is a litte bit complex, so bear with me...

I'm building a web page where a user can add different locations on a map. The app uses the google maps api.

The locations added are sent via ajax to a php page where they are stored in a session variable. Another function then prints out the locations so that the user can see a list with the locations he/she has added.

When the user has added x number of locations they name the map they created, fill out a form and then sends the fom to the same php page which stores the locations. When the form is sent, the locations, together with the form info is stored in a db.

Everything works fine, but the user also has the option to delete a location by clicking the location marker on the map while creating the map. This click event sends an ajax post with the lat and lgn of the location and this specific location is then deleted from the session which holds the location information.

The location then also disappears from the list with added locations.

This also works fine, but when I try to save the form (also via ajax) nothing happens. The form is also sent via ajax.

So, to summarize: everything works fine if I don't delete any locations before sending form, but if I delete a location then it doesn't work.

I will of course provide sample code if someone could guide me in the right direction as to where the problem might lie.

EDIT

Ok, so here is the response when I have added two locations: The respons is encoded as xml for google maps reasons.

```
<markers><marker titel="Test" comment="Test" lat="59.3082270911156" lng="18.060922622680664"      name="" type="Parkering" score="3" /><marker titel="test2" comment="test2" lat="59.3082034749666"      lng="18.060929998755455" name="" type="Parkering" score="5" /></markers>
```

If I save the map + form now, It will work fine.

This is the response after I have deleted a marker from the map:

```
 <markers><marker titel="Test" comment="Test" lat="59.3082270911156" lng="18.060922622680664"    name="" type="Parkering" score="3" /></markers>
```

To me It looks just fine.

This is the function which is triggered when the user clicks a marker (ie deletes it)

```
  function close(marker2, lati, lngi, infoWindow, map) {

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "click", function() {
    marker2.setMap(null);
    infoWindow.close(map, marker2);

    $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'test3.php',
                data: "lati=" + lati + "&lngi=" + lngi,
                success: function(data) {

                printResult(data); 

                $('#send').unbind();


                }
        }); 




        });






    };
```

This is the function which delets the location from the session:

```
 $val1 = $_GET['lati'];

 $val2 = $_GET['lngi'];



 $newarray = removeElementWithValue($_SESSION['infomarker'], "lat", "lng", $val1, $val2);





 function removeElementWithValue(&$array, $key1, $key2, $value1, $value2){
      foreach($array as $subKey => $subArray){
      if($subArray[$key1] == $value1) {
      if($subArray[$key2] == $value2) 

         unset($array[$subKey]);

      }

 }
 return $array;

 }
```

I get no js error, and as you can see above the delete function works fine and I get a healthy response.

Comment: I think you want to include code for the ajax calls, the html of the form then probably the php that processes the ajax call.

Comment: You need to post your code, it's like telling a mechanic your car is broken without looking at the car.

Comment: Yes, I do understand this, but I was hoping that my general description would suffice. It's quite a lot of code.

Comment: @user1009453 What does the debug info show based on my answer?

Comment: I've added some code now...I get no error messages at all.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've identified the problem in that there is an error with the data and/or PHP endpoint that handles saving after making a deletion.

Here is how I would debug this if I were to look at your code:

1. Open my web inspector's network tab and examine the data being sent via AJAX to ensure that the structure is correct.
2. In the PHP endpoint, I would `var_dump($_POST)` to inspect the output. This will be sent over the wire and you can see the output in your web inspector.
3. Open the console to check for any JS errors.

If you do those three things, you're more than likely going to identify the bug. Good luck.